# Ffmpeg change audio file bitrate and pass the output to pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I used to change the bitrate of audio files by using

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ab 96k output.mp3
```

and it works perfectly. Now I want to pass the output as pipe in Ffmpeg and perform some other task. I have took the reference of this [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) and modified the above ffmpeg command into

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ab 96k pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/output.mp3
```

But this doesn't work.
Only if i use pipe as below then it works.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f mp3 pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/output.mp3
```

But this doesn't change the bitrate of the audio. Can anyone please help me how can I achieve my target of changing the bitrate and passing the output as Pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the output format manually. When outputting to file, ffmpeg guesses format based on extension, which can't be done when piping.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ab 96k -f mp3 pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/output.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I was missing the output format. Also is there anything that I need to add to make it more reliable.